# React-Redux - How to set fields inside state of application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning [Fractal Structure](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) with React and Redux but I found blocked when I want set a state of application.

I 'll try to explain my problem

src/router/Counter/index.js

```
import { injectReducer } from '../../store/reducers'

export default (store) => ({
  path: 'counter',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const Counter = require('./containers/CounterContainer').default
      const reducer = require('./modules/counter').default

      /*  Add the reducer to the store on key 'counter'  */
      injectReducer(store, { key: 'counter', reducer })

      cb(null, Counter)

    }, 'counter')
  }
})
```

src/router/Counter/modules/counter.js

```
// ------------------------------------
// Constants
// ------------------------------------
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT'

// ------------------------------------
// Actions
// ------------------------------------
export function increment (value = 1) {
  return {
    type: COUNTER_INCREMENT,
    payload: value
  }
}

export const actions = {
  increment
}

// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [COUNTER_INCREMENT]: (state, action) => state + action.payload
}

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = 0
export default function counterReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

src/routes/Counter/containers/CounterContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { increment } from '../modules/counter'

import Counter from 'components/Counter'

const mapActionCreators = {
  increment: () => increment(1)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  counter: state.counter
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators)(Counter)
```

And I want to achieve set more fields in counter state for I can pass the props by separated. i.e:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      max: state.counter.max
      min: state.counter.min
})
```

So, how to set fields inside state.counter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use reducer to update sate properties. Something like this for your counter.

```
function counter(state = initialState, payload) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_COUNTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        counter: {max:payload.max,min:payload.min}
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: I need set the initialState with min and max ?

Comment: yes it can be an empty object. This is good place to start http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: I will try adapt the code as you suggest. Thank you!